# Excel vba - getting rid of .activate and.select

Tags: excel, vba

My code below is run from ThisWorkbook. It opens up wb_gr (already done), and I'm trying to do a AutoFill in sheet "sh_9_overtid_år" from D3 and down to end of last used cell in row A.
Code is working, but I want to get rid of all .activate and .selcet, and run it with sheets hidden. But I haven't got the skills to pull it off... Anyone that can help me with how to modify this bit of code?

```
wb_gr.Activate
sh_9_overtid_år.Select
Range("D3:D3").Select
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D3:D" & lr), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: Under "Related" is [How to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `sh_9_overtid_år` is a fully qualified range (and `AutoFill` is required due to `D3` containing a formula), this should do it:

```
With sh_9_overtid_år
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("D3:D3").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("D3:D" & lr), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked great. Thanks a lot for helping out.

Comment: Don't forget to mark one as an answer if you're happy with it - whichever suited your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use With statement to work with hidden sheets. Also, Autofill is not needed here I think.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim lr As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  '<== change this to your workbook.worksheet e.g. maybe  wb_gr.sh_9_overtid_år

        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("D3:D" & lr).Value = .Range("D3")

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This way of doing it also worked great. Thanks a lot for helping out.